# gcc vector extension assign operator

Tags: c++, gcc, vector

I'm experiment with gcc vector extension and I don't know how assign data to a vector

```
typedef int simdScore __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
simdScore x ={0,0,0,0};
simdScore y= {5,5,5,5};
x += y;

//ERROR by compiler
x = {1,2,3,4};
```

x = {1,2,3,4} seems to be usable only for initialization, but it's not possbile use it after the initialization. Is there some way to load data in a vector without creating a local variabile or doing:

```
x[0] =1;
x[1] =2;
x[2] =3;
x[3] =4;
```

thank you all

Comment: _"I'm experiment with gcc vector extension"_ Sure you'll need that in preference of `std::array` from the current standard?

Comment: For broadcast you can do `simdScore y =  5 - (simdScore){};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `x = simdScore{1, 2, 3, 4};` work?

Comment: Is that a question or an answer? (or a comment?)

Comment: I tried the c++ like x = simdScore(1,2,3,4); but it doesn't work. you solution is correct

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `x = simdScore{1, 2, 3, 4};` only works for C++11 or later. If you need to do it in C++98, does `x = (simdScore){1, 2, 3, 4};` work?